# Spring Security SAML SSO - how to specify url to which user is routed after authentication

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0

I am working on integrating Spring Security SAML into our existing security infrastructure, to handle partner SSO. I am looking at the sample app that comes with Spring Security SAML as a template.

I see that in SAML, the SP must specify the AssertionConsumerServiceBinding to provide the return url to which the IdP will send the AuthenticationResponse.

With the Spring Security SAML sample, we set this to:

http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SSO.

However, after the IdP posts the AuthenticationResponse back to that url, the user's browser is redirected to

http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample.

Can I specify a specific url to which the user will be redirected after the SSO authentication succeeds? I am not finding any documentation on this and am not seeing how it happens in the sample app.

Answer (score 2):

One specifies the url to which the user should be routed after successful authentication via the defaultTargetUrl value in the successRedirectHandler bean's definition.